Google Protobuf in message add array of values, one string and array of objects
In good protobuf, i want to create json like below. how can i acheive that?
{
Action:"Add"
"Row":[{
 {
    "value": "29170944"
 },
 { 
     "value":[{no:1},{no:2}] 
}]
}

